# How do I create a .pfx file on asp.net core 1.0 projects

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing, pfx

I am able to sign .net framework 4.6.1 and below projects by following these steps:

1. Right-click on the project
2. Click the Signing tab
3. Check the "Sign the assembly"
4. Follow the prompts to create a new strong key file (view screenshot)

How do I now create a new strong key file on .net core 1.0 projects?

[image]

Comment: Also see [Introduction to Code Signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN. Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.